# Solve a Solitaire Chess Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, chess

Recently, I was introduced to a puzzle game known as [Solitaire Chess](http://www.thinkfun.com/products/solitaire-chess/). I'll summarize the rules here:

- The board is a 4x4 checkerboard.
- All pieces are the same color (no teams) and all pieces can capture any other piece.
- Every move must be a capture. No moving to empty squares.
- There must be exactly one piece remaining at the end.
- All pieces move exactly like they do in chess, with one modification: the pawn can capture in any diagonal direction (which technically makes it a [*ferz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferz_(chess))). For the benefit of those who may not know, I have included movement diagrams.
- None of the other rules of chess (such as check, castling, etc.) apply here. It's all about captures.

**King (K)**

```
K * . . | * K * . | * * * .
* * . . | * * * . | * K * .
. . . . | . . . . | * * * .
. . . . | . . . . | . . . .
```

**Queen (Q)**

```
Q * * * | * Q * * | * * * .
* * . . | * * * . | * Q * *
* . * . | . * . * | * * * .
* . . * | . * . . | . * . *
```

**Rook (R)**

```
R * * * | * R * * | . * . .
* . . . | . * . . | * R * *
* . . . | . * . . | . * . .
* . . . | . * . . | . * . .
```

**Bishop (B)**

```
B . . . | . B . . | * . * .
. * . . | * . * . | . B . .
. . * . | . . . * | * . * .
. . . * | . . . . | . . . *
```

**Knight (N)**

```
N . . . | . N . . | . . . *
. . * . | . . . * | . N . .
. * . . | * . * . | . . . *
. . . . | . . . . | * . * .
```

**Pawn (P)**

```
P . . . | . P . . | * . * .
. * . . | * . * . | . P . .
. . . . | . . . . | * . * .
. . . . | . . . . | . . . .
```

### Input/output

For reference, the sample puzzle from the Solitaire Chess webpage will be used:

```
. . . .
. B . .
R P . .
. . . N
```

The solution is to take the pawn with the knight, then take the knight with the rook, and finally take the bishop with the rook.

**Input**

Input must be in one of three forms; you are free to pick the one that is most convenient for you.

- A string of characters such as `.....B..RP.....N`, with or without newlines. The character representing a blank space may be any character that isn't one of `KQRBNP`.
- A list of lists (or a flattened list) where the elements are either characters or numbers, like so: `[['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'B', '.', '.'], ['R', 'P', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'N']]` or `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0], [3, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5]]`. For the former, the character that represents a blank space may be anything that isn't one of `KQRBNP`. For the latter, I've given pieces the number that corresponds to their rank in my earlier list of moves (`1` is a king, `4` is a bishop, `6` is a pawn, etc.). You are free to change the numbering.
- A list of coordinates where each element has the form `[x, y, 'c']`, like so: `[[1, 2, 'B'], [0, 1, 'R'], [1, 1, 'P'], [3, 0, 'N']]`.

If you pick one of the list-based input formats, the separators and delimiters may be any reasonable and understandable characters.

**Output**

Output must be a sequence of moves or a sequence of board states. Some puzzles have more than one solution; you may output one or all of them. If you choose to output a sequence of board states, each board must be in one of the three input formats, with a reasonable separator (such as newlines) between them.

If you choose to output a sequence of moves, they must be expressed as a list of pairs of coordinate pairs, like so: `[[[3,0], [1,1]], [[0,1], [1,1]], [[1,1], [1,2]]]`. `[0,0]` represents the bottom left corner, and again, separating and delimiting characters may be any reasonable choice.

If a given board cannot be solved, output any falsy value (`0`, empty string, etc.). If a given board has fewer than two pieces, behavior is undefined.

### Test Cases

*Note: outputs are only given as a list of pairs of coordinates since the other formats should be fairly easy to check for correctness (and I didn't feel like typing out all the possible output formats). Also, for the puzzles that have more than one solution, only one possibility is provided.*

**Input 1:**

```
. . . N
. . . .
. R . .
. . B .

...N.....R....B.

[['.', '.', '.', 'N'], ['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'R', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', 'B', '.']]

[[0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0]]

[[3, 3, 'N'], [1, 1, 'R'], [2, 0, 'B']]
```

**Output 1:**

```
[[[2,0], [1,1]], [[1,1], [3,3]]]
```

**Input 2:**

```
. . . .
. B . .
R P . .
. . . N

.....B..RP.....N

[['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'B', '.', '.'], ['R', 'P', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'N']]

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0], [3, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5]]

[[1, 2, 'B'], [0, 1, 'R'], [1, 1, 'P'], [3, 0, 'N']]
```

**Output 2:**

```
[[[3,0], [1,1]], [[0,1], [1,1]], [[1,1], [1,2]]]
```

**Input 3:**

```
. N R .
B . . .
N . . B
. . P .

.NR.B...N..B..P.

[['.', 'N', 'R', '.'], ['B', '.', '.', '.'], ['N', '.', '.', 'B'], ['.', '.', 'P', '.']]

[[0, 5, 3, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 6, 0]]

[[1, 3, 'N'], [2, 3, 'R'], [0, 2, 'B'], [0, 1, 'N'], [3, 1, 'B'], [2, 0, 'P']]
```

**Output 3:**

```
[[[2,0], [3,1]], [[0,1], [1,3]], [[0,2], [1,3]], [[2,3], [1,3]], [[3,1], [1,3]]]
```

**Input 4:**

```
. . . N
. . . R
R B B .
N P P .

...N...RRBB.NPP.

[['.', '.', '.', 'N'], ['.', '.', '.', 'R'], ['R', 'B', 'B', '.'], ['N', 'P', 'P', '.']]

[[0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 3], [3, 4, 4, 0], [5, 6, 6, 0]]

[[3, 3, 'N'], [3, 2, 'R'], [0, 1, 'R'], [1, 1, 'B'], [2, 1, 'B'], [0, 0, 'N'], [1, 0, 'P'], [2, 0, 'P']]
```

**Output 4:**

```
[[[2,1], [3,2]], [[1,1], [3,3]], [[3,2], [1,0]], [[3,3], [0,0]], [[0,1], [0,0]], [[0,0], [1,0]], [[1,0], [2,0]]]
```

**Input 5:**

```
P . . .
. R . .
R . R .
. R . .

P....R..R.R..R..

[['P', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'R', '.', '.'], ['R', '.', 'R', '.'], ['.', 'R', '.', '.']]

[[6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0]]

[[0, 3, 'P'], [1, 2, 'R'], [0, 1, 'R'], [2, 1, 'R'], [1, 0, 'R']]
```

**Output 5:**

```
[[[0,3], [1,2]], [[1,2], [2,1]], [[2,1], [1,0]], [[1,0], [0,1]]]
```

**Input 6:**

```
. P . N
K . . .
. . B .
. . R Q

.P.NK.....B...RQ

[['.', 'P', '.', 'N'], ['K', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', 'B', '.'], ['.', '.', 'R', 'Q']]

[[0, 6, 0, 5], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 3, 2]]

[[1, 3, 'P'], [3, 3, 'N'], [0, 2, 'K'], [2, 1, 'B'], [2, 0, 'R'], [3, 0, 'Q']]
```

**Output 6:**

```
[[[3,0], [2,0]], [[2,0], [2,1]], [[3,3], [2,1]], [[2,1], [1,3]], [[0,2], [1,3]]]
```

Comment: there is a little mistake in output 1, it should be [[[2,0], [1,1]], [[1,1], [3,3]]]

Comment: Also, as an additional note, the king is really a Mann (can be captured, but has the same move rules) (Fairy chess nomenclature is fun)

Comment: @Damien: Good spot! Thanks.

Comment: Is it OK to include the piece symbol in the output? Such as: `[["R", [2, 0], [1, 1]], ["N", [1, 1], [3, 3]]]`

Comment: @Arnauld: Yes, that would be okay. Somewhat strange though since you're listing the piece that's captured, not the capturing piece.

Comment: You're right. Actually, I'm now showing both the capturing and captured pieces. Hope that's okay too. ;)

Comment: @Arnauld: That would definitely be better.

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, <s>226</s> <s>195</s> <s>191</s> 188 bytes

Returns a list of all solutions. Each solution is a list of moves.
Returns an empty list if there is no solution.

Saved 4 bytes Thanks to Lynn.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/lK6q8G)

```haskell
m"P"=[2]
m"N"=[5]
m"K"=[1,2]
m"R"=[1,4,9]
m"B"=[2,8,18]
m _=m"B"++m"R"
l%x=[z|z<-l,fst z/=x]
f[_]=[[]]
f l=[(i,j):r|(i@(s,t),a)<-l,(j@(u,v),_)<-l,(s-u)^2+(t-v)^2`elem`m a,r<-f$(j,a):l%i%j]
```

Usage:

```haskell
main = do 
    print $ f [((3, 3), "N"), ((1, 1), "R")]
    putStrLn""
    mapM_ print $ f [((3, 3), "N"), ((1, 1), "R"), ((2, 0), "B")]
    putStrLn""
    mapM_ print $ f [((1, 2), "B"), ((0, 1), "R"), ((1, 1), "P"), ((3, 0), "N")]
    putStrLn""
    mapM_ print $ f [((1, 3), "P"), ((3, 3), "N"), ((0, 2), "K"), ((2, 1), "B"), ((2, 0), "R"), ((3, 0), "Q")]
```

Output:

```haskell
[]

[((2,0),(1,1)),((1,1),(3,3))]

[((3,0),(1,1)),((0,1),(1,1)),((1,1),(1,2))]

[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(1,3)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,3),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(3,0)),((2,0),(3,0)),((3,0),(3,3)),((3,3),(1,3))]
[((0,2),(1,3)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((0,2),(1,3)),((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((0,2),(1,3)),((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((2,1),(3,0)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,0),(3,0)),((3,0),(3,3)),((3,3),(1,3))]
[((2,1),(3,0)),((2,0),(3,0)),((3,0),(3,3)),((3,3),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((2,1),(3,0)),((2,0),(3,0)),((3,0),(3,3)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,3),(1,3))]
[((2,1),(3,0)),((2,0),(3,0)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,0),(3,3)),((3,3),(1,3))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((2,0),(2,1)),((3,0),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(3,3)),((3,3),(1,3)),((1,3),(0,2)),((0,2),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,1),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3)),((1,3),(3,3))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,1)),((2,0),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((2,0),(2,1)),((0,2),(1,3)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((1,3),(0,2)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,1),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,3))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,0),(0,2)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((3,3),(2,1)),((1,3),(0,2)),((2,0),(0,2)),((2,1),(0,2))]
[((3,0),(2,0)),((0,2),(1,3)),((2,0),(2,1)),((3,3),(2,1)),((2,1),(1,3))]
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Inlining `!` saves a few bytes: ``f l=[(i,j):r|(i@(s,t),a)<-l,(j@(u,v),_)<-l%i,r<-f$(j,a):l%i%j,(s-u)^2+(t-v)^2`elem`m a]``

Comment: Nice! What does the output look like?

Comment: `[[((2,0),(1,1)),((1,1),(3,3))]]`. A list of solutions, where a solution is a list of moves, where a move is `((x1,y1),(x2,y2))`.

Comment: `m"P"=[1]`
Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>372</s> <s>361</s> 358 bytes

It (still) needs some optimizing. But here is a <s>first</s> <s>2nd</s> 3rd attempt.

```
b=>{for(n=-4,b=[...b];n<36;b.splice(n+=8,0,0,0,0,0));l=[];(M=(P,u,Z,z,L)=>{for(P=u=n;u--;)
for((z=[640,164928,641,259,899,898]["PNBRQK".indexOf(b[u])])&&P++,L=1,s=z&1;z>>=1;L++)for(Z
=u;z&1&!((Z+=L)&n)&&(b[Z]<'A'||!(M(l.push([b[Z],[u&3,31-u>>3],b[u],[Z&3,31-Z>>3]]),b[Z]=b[u
],b[u]='.'),b[u]=b[Z],b[Z]=l.pop()[0]))&&s||(L=-L,Z=u,L<0););P-37||console.log(l)})()}
```

Output format:

```
// Puzzle #1
[["B", [2, 0], "R", [1, 1]], ["B", [1, 1], "N", [3, 3]]]
```

Example:

```js
let F =
b=>{for(n=-4,b=[...b];n<36;b.splice(n+=8,0,0,0,0,0));l=[];(M=(P,u,Z,z,L)=>{for(P=u=n;u--;)for((z=[640,164928,641,259,899,898]["PNBRQK".indexOf(b[u])])&&P++,L=1,s=z&1;z>>=1;L++)for(Z=u;z&1&!((Z+=L)&n)&&(b[Z]<'A'||!(M(l.push([b[Z],[u&3,31-u>>3],b[u],[Z&3,31-Z>>3]]),b[Z]=b[u],b[u]='.'),b[u]=b[Z],b[Z]=l.pop()[0]))&&s||(L=-L,Z=u,L<0););P-37||console.log(l)})()}

console.log("Puzzle #1");
F("...N.....R....B.");
console.log("Puzzle #2");
F(".....B..RP.....N");
```